# Get page sources using a FirefoxDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm working on a library that needs to automatically wait for a page to fully load before taking a screenshot. For this specific case I need to get an array of the page sources using a Firefox WebDriver that looks something like this when you inspect element in Chrome:

[image: The page sources I want to get]

I've done some research and all I've found is how to get the HTML source of the page. I looked through the source and could not find a way to get the page sources I am looking for. Is there a way to do this with a Firefox WebDriver programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "page sources?"

Comment: The list of images and files in the Sources then Page tab in the screenshot.

Comment: That just appears to be the URLs of all the style sheets, JavaScript files, images and other media that is downloaded while rendering the page. You can just get all the `<style>`, `<script>` and `<img>` tags on the page, and you should be able to get mostly the same information. Things get tricky when a style sheet imports a background image, or a script sets the style of an element to import a background image.

Comment: I had a look through the `driver.PageSource` for `<style>`, `<script>` and `<img>` tags and could not find the urls as seen in the screenshot. I also tried looking for urls containing `cbk?cb_client=maps_sv.tactile` but could not find any of the ones in the screenshot.

Comment: It might be a timing issue too. JavaScript might be adding images to the page dynamically, and those images might not be available at the time you grab the page source. You might need to select those elements by xpath or CSS selector, and wait for their presence on the page.

Comment: The images should be present as I waited 10 seconds after navigating to the page before getting the source. The images were also visible and fully loaded at the time of taking the screenshot in the driver window.

Comment: Are you sure they are `<img>` tags and not background images? You need to figure that out.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure since they don't show up as background  images or `<img>` tags. If you have the time could you have a look at the [source](https://pastebin.com/Fjm7xKFV)?